# Add rows of textboxes with a click of a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, row

I am badly stuck on this problem and would appreciate any kinds of helps! I have to create a page where the user can add more rows by clicking a button. For example, I have the first row with 2 text boxes (name and birth dates), second row with the "Add Row" button. When the user clicks the "Add Row" button, the first row should be cloned and repeated...but the user can't add more than 5 rows. Later all the information need to be saved in a SQL table. How this can be achieved in C#?

I am attaching my sample ASP.NET. Can any one PLEASE help me?

PS: I have already read and tried "How to: Add Rows and Cells Dynamically to a Table Web Server Control"....but that's not working for me.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Testing Adding Rows</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>    
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" width="400" style="border:[none][0]; border-color:White; border-style:hidden">                
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server" nowrap="nowrap" Width= "70">
                    <asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text="Your Name" Font-Size="X-Small"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server" nowrap="nowrap" Width= "100">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_name" runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:TextBox> 
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="nameValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb_name" Font-Size="Smaller">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </asp:TableCell> 

                <asp:TableCell runat="server" nowrap="nowrap" Width= "70">
                    <asp:Label ID="dateLabel" runat="server" Text="Birthdate" Font-Size="Smaller" ></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>                        
                <asp:TableCell runat="server" Width= "100">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_date" runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="dateValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb_date" Font-Size="Smaller">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </asp:TableCell>

            </asp:TableRow>


            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow2" runat="server"> 
                <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="left" Width= "100">
                    <asp:Button ID="addRow" runat="server" Height="22px" Text="Add Row" 
                                 ToolTip="Click to add another row" onclick="ButtonAddRow_Click" />
                </asp:TableCell> 
            </asp:TableRow> 


            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow3" runat="server">  
                <asp:TableCell runat="server" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">    </asp:TableCell>

                <asp:TableCell runat="server"  align="left" nowrap="nowrap" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <asp:Label ID="msg" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LogonValidationSummary" HeaderText="All the fields (*) are required." DisplayMode="SingleParagraph"
                                           Font-Italic="true" ShowSummary="True" EnableClientScript="true" runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller"/> 
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>

             <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow4" runat="server"> 
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell10" runat="server" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">       </asp:TableCell>

                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell11" runat="server" align="left" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmit" runat="server" Height="22px" Text="Submit" Width="79px" onclick="ButtonSubmit_Click" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>

        </asp:Table>    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Pranay yes, I will definitely do that. btw, liked your idea of using GridView control, I will try that out.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your helps! However, I am still stuck on the part where I will have to collect all the info from the rows and save them to a SQL table, can anyone please help me with that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like if you make use of GridView control and than add row runtime to gridview rather than using table. That would minize your effort also code.

here is code for you : [Adding Dynamic Rows in GridView with TextBoxes](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/04/adding-dynamic-rows-in-gridview-with-textboxes.aspx) 
[image]

Comment: Thank you, now at least it's cloning the first row correctly. However, I am still stuck on how to gather all the info from the rows and save them to a SQL table, any suggestions plz?

Comment: yes you can read data put it into one xaml and than you can make use of openxaml to insert bulk data

Answer (score 1):

This codes snippet is just a hint that you can do this way..

```
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
     for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
     {
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
           tb.ID = "TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j;
           cell.Controls.Add(tb);
           row.Cells.Add(cell);
      }

     Table1.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. However, as I have already mentioned that I tried this one from MSDN page and isn't not doing exactly what I am looking for (after clicking the ADD ROW button only once, this generates and displays all 5 rows at once...whereas I want to add one row at a time). Thanks anyway!!

Comment: So, you can do this just calling it in button click event, is there any problem ?

Comment: Yes, I did exactly how they are showing here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bewx260.aspx but that's giving me different output than what i was expecting. Oh, while trying this out, I did move the "Table1.Rows.Add(tRow)" line right after the inner loop.